# Site redirected you too many times - nginx (certbot) sites-available file

Tags: redirect, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, certbot

Hello stackoverflow community. I need your help.

I installed certbot for let's encrypt ssl on a digital ocean hosted site (LEMP config in ubuntu 16.4) and I noticed that the site redirects too many times:

> This page isn’t working.
>   placeholder.com redirected you too many times.

Here is my sites-available/default file:

```
 ##
 # You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
 # of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
 # http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
 # http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
 # http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
 #
 # Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
 # file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
 #
 # Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
 ##

 # Default server configuration
 #
 server {
         server_name placeholder.com www.placeholder.com;
         return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

     listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
     listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/placeholder.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/placeholder.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
     include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

 }

 server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-placeholder.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
  # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 47.101.148.243;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}
    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
 }
 }
 # Virtual Host configuration for example.com
 #
 # You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
 # to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
 #
 #server {
 #       listen 80;
 #       listen [::]:80;
 #
 #       server_name example.com;
 #
 #       root /var/www/example.com;
 #       index index.html;
 #
 #       location / {
 #               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 #       }
 #}


 server {

    if ($host = www.placeholder.com) {
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     } # managed by Certbot

     if ($host = placeholder.com) {
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     } # managed by Certbot


         listen 80 default_server;
         listen [::]:80 default_server;
         server_name placeholder.com www.placeholder.com;
         return 404; # managed by Certbot

 }
```

Could you help me find where the redirect loop is forming, and how to fix it, please?